# Реять - этимология

Tags: этимология, однокоренные-слова

Прочитала обсуждения слов "рей" и "рея". Там еще в обсуждении ссылались на слово "реять".
Скажите, пожалуйста, разве оно родственно слову "рея" (или "рей")? Насколько я понимаю, название большей части корабельных снастей попало в русский язык из голландского при Петре I.
И вообще, интересно было бы узнать этимологию слова "реять". И еще, интересно, почему оно более... пафосной, скажем так, чем "развеваться"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, не родственно. Рей - голландское (брус). Реять - глагол, заимствованный из старославянского, восходит к той же основе, что и в словах ринуться, рой, река, как утверждают Крылов и Фасмер:

Реять, ре́ю, укр. рíяти, рíю "роиться (о пчелах)", др.-русск. рѣяти, рѣю "толкать, расталкивать, отгонять", ст.-слав. рѣѩти, рѣѭ ἐπείγειν, συνωθεῖν (Супр.), болг. ре́я се "ношусь повсюду".
Связано чередованием гласных с ри́нуть(ся), рой, река́.

http://enc-dic.com/fasmer/Rejat-11330.html

А пафосный, потому что старославянизм, старославянизмы всегда пафосны: реяли знамёна, а флаги развевались. Косынка тоже может развеваться - это бытовое слово, а реять косынка не может, это будет стилистическая ошибка.

Comment: В принципе - да. Есть уточнее.
Слово "брус" в голландском - straal. Рей - точно так же. (Это и ответ одному участнику, что-то там про "круглость" утверждающему).

Есть слово "ree" [рэ'э]- олень, оно по произношению ближе всего к русскому "рея". 
Но дкмаю, речь не о нем, а о слове "ra" [ра] - точном аналогу английского "yard" (двор). Этим-то "ярдом" и на английском, и на голландском называется вся конструкция для "прогулок" по реям - т.е. место, где можно находиться.   
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yard_%28sailing%29  
https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ra_%28zeil%29

С остальным согласен.

Comment: вот именно поэтому ваша братия и стирает, как только в русском языке обнаруживаются слова-исходники.
Про слово рай я уже говорил.

Comment: Да и вообще, большая часть названий в  корабельном такелаже имеет русские исходники.  
Вот только один пример:    
ют-hut  в нидерландском, а в русском уют, приют.  
Вполне наш хутор.

Comment: А какая связь между носовой частью палубы и домашним уютом?

Comment: Видимо, ИХ братия "стирала" (см. comment @fatyalink) на палубе, чтобы уют на хуторе не пачкать:)

Comment: Да нет, тут было довольно шумно... Не до уюта...)))  
Сначала приходилось "ИХ" жемчуга в куче навоза искать, потом уже пошел чистый продукт, без жемчугов. Обидно что кое-какие мысли пострадали по существу... Вот без них и вся "дискуссия" непонятна стала.   
Там, если опустить громы и молнии, fatyalink декларировал свое право критиковать всех и вся с позиций вульгарной этимологии, поэтому ему очень не нравился фасмеровский (и не только) подход - и выводы на нем построенные. Следы этих воин мы и наблюдаем.

Comment: Вот это знатоки корабельного дела, спорят до опупения. Бак--носовая часть корабля... Ют--кормовая надстройка, там каюты уютные.
Шире шаг, товарищи матросы, матрацы вам поперек палубы никто не раскантует, остается падать за борт, если держать по курсу не получается, полубак вам на клотике!!!!

Answer (score -2):

Кажется голл. РЕЙ произошло из русс. ВЕЯТЬ, ВЕЯЛ, которое дало так же в латинском EVALLO = веять, VALLUS = маленькая веялка, немецкое WEHEN = веять и английское WAVE = реять. 
В испанском это, вероятно, AVENTAR = веять.

Comment: Сомневаетесь?
Не спешите судить, друзья.
Таких многосоставных совпадений между русско-западноевропейскими парами очень много. Почему-то они остались незаметными Но логику никто не отменял. Как бы ни была сильна сравнительная лингвистика, объяснить этот феномен простым отнекиванием не удастся. Нужны убедительные аргументы, к которым языковедение пока не готово. Нужно время чтобы этот переосмыслить.

Comment: Например, русск.УДАЧА, которое Фасмер забывает упомянуть в своем словаре, скорее всего родственно лат. AUDACIA (смелость) и ,стало быть, и англ. AUDACITY (дерзость).

Можно провести расследование и научно опровергнуть меня. 
Но это никак не объяснит указанноесовпадение. Повторю мысль - подобных "случайных" совпадений так много, что называть их так, т.е. совпадениями, как-то язык не поворачивается.